# GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker won't open browser when running on IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, youtube-data-api

I have a Web App running on IIS 8. This "Web App" only runs locally, we use it as a desktop app that we open through `Google Chrome`. I'm trying to upload a video to `YouTube` through their API. Basically my problem is here:

```
uc = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                         new ClientSecrets
                         {
                             ClientId = CLIENTID,
                             ClientSecret = CLIENTSECRET
                         },
                            new[] { YouTubeService.Scope.Youtube },
                            "user",
                            CancellationToken.None,
                            new Google.Apis.Util.Store.FileDataStore(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), "Google.Apis.Auth.YouTube")));
```

This works perfectly on a console application or when running my web app in IIS Express on Visual Studio, but when I try to authenticate when my app is running on IIS it just hangs there an no browser is opened asking for authentication, I thought that this was because IIS doesn't have a UI (the same problem that using this method in Windows Services)

So I created a console app that will be called from my IIS app. When running my console app through `cmd.exe` it works great as expected, but when I run it from my IIS app using `Process` it hangs again in the same place.

My IIS App Pool runs as the main administrator user. Why can't I use `GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker` inside IIS? Even calling a console app fails?

Comment: Have you found a solution for that?

Comment: @Caaarlos I ended up using client-side authentication

Comment: Ok, thank you. I will try it!